# Como faço para utilizar o valor de uma variável JavaScript em uma variável PHP para posteriormente usar esse valor em outras páginas do site?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tenho uma página Web sobre animais e veterinários que preciso capturar de uma lista um identificador do animal (cd_pet) do banco de dados e utilizá-lo em outra página quando clicado, utilizando a linguagem PHP para fornecer as mesmas informações do animal nesta outra página. 
O problema é que utilizando um while para percorrer todos os animais do banco para buscar as informações do animal, não consigo clicar no animal escolhido da lista e capturar o identificador (cd_pet) do animal selecionado e colocar em uma variável PHP.

O código utilizado é esse:

**PHP/HTML**

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  $cd_usuario = $row['cd_usuario'];
    if ($cd_usuario == $ID) {
    ?> 
    <li><a href=<?php echo "Perfil_de_usuario/".$row['nm_pet'].$row['cd_ra'].".php"; ?> onclick="pegarRA('<?php echo  $row['cd_pet'] ?> ')">
    <span id="esconder"></span>
    <table style="width:80%; border: 1px solid black" >
    <?php echo
    " <tr><td class = 'ra' id='ra' for='feed-padrao'> <b>RA:</b> " . $row["cd_ra"].
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Nome do Pet: </b>" . $row["nm_pet"]. 
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Genero: </b>" . $row["ic_genero"].  
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b> Data Nascimento: </b>" . $row["dt_nascimento"]. 
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Tipo de animal: </b>" . $row["nm_tipo_animal"]. 
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Raça: </b>" . $row["nm_raca"].
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Cor: </b>" . $row["ds_cor"]. 
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Comportamento: </b>" . $row["ds_comportamento"]. 
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Nome do Proprietario: </b>" . $row["nm_usuario"]. 
    " </td></tr><tr><td><b>Email do Proprietario: </b>" . $row["cd_email"]."</td></tr><br>"; 
    ?>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
//TESTE PARA CAPTURAR O IDENTIFICADOR
function pegarRA(cd_pet){
 var cdEscondido = cd_pet
 document.getElementById("esconder").innerHTML = cdEscondido;
 document.getElementById("esconder").style.visibility = "hidden";
 alert(cdEscondido);
}

//FUNÇÃO PARA DEIXAR A LISTA DE BUSCA AUTOMÁTICA
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você comenta sobre `cd_pet` mas esse valor nem existe no código, assim fica confuso. O exatamente você quer fazer?

Comment: eu cortei o código para não ficar muito extenso.. O cd_pet é auto_increment e é do banco de dados... ele está citado dentro do onclick="pegarRA()", que faz que quando eu clicar na lista, o valor de cd_pet é capturado do banco e vai para a função que chama um alert (o alert só usei para teste)... mas eu só sei usar o valor para utilizá-lo na mesma página após o pet ter sido selecionado na lista, porém, quero utilizá-lo em outra página.. e não sei fazer isso se não for em PHP.

Comment: Mas você quer redirecionar para outra página e pegar o valor nesta ou precisa fazer alguma requisição assíncrona para obter mais detalhes do registro?

Comment: Vou simular aqui... eu sou proprietário do animal e estou na página A e quero escolher um dos meus pets para cadastrar ou excluir mais informações, informações que apenas o proprietário do pet pode cadastrar ou excluir, devido a permissão... 
Na página A, existe uma lista com algumas informações prévias (um resumo) do animal, como nome do pet, raça, data de nascimento e etc, tudo numa tabela que, quando eu clico, me redireciona para a página B, que é onde contém todas as informações do Pet e é nesta página B que eu consigo cadastrar ou excluir as informações.

Comment: Um exemplo de uma das coisas que pretendo fazer, é o proprietário do animal poder excluir o perfil (todas as informações) do animal, na página B, só que para isso, ele deve escolher qual dos seus animais da lista A ele pretende acessar.

Comment: Esse código que postei é da página A, mais precisamente é a lista dos pets cadastrados.